# Configuring AngularJS modules - how does it affect the other modules in the app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I have two Angular modules, `A` and `B`.
`A` has no deps, some configurations and some filters:

```
angular.module('A', [])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
    // set common headers for $http requests
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common = {...};
    })
    .filter('myFilter', function () {
        // create a filter
    });
```

`B` depends on `A`, so it goes something like:

```
angular.module('B', ['A'])...
```

I know that `B` depending on `A` means I can use `myFilter` inside `B` views.

The question is: does the code in `myFilter` benefits from the `$http` common headers I set inside the `config()` function of the `A` module (since `myFilter` belongs to `A`)?

And when making HTTP requests from inside the `B` module, are the common headers the ones I set inside `A` or they are not affected from the configuration inside `A`?

True to both the questions makes enough sense to me: I config some common headers in the `A` module that I'll use inside the filters that the `A` module provides, but I want those same common headers out of my way when I'm inside the `B` module; still, when I'm inside `B` views, I want to be able to use `A` filters with their specific common headers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i think. Like any other angular `$httpProvider` is also singleton in nature which very well means any changes to it from any where including any module would affect other, or in other words changes are global.

Comment: I think Chandermani is correct, if you want to add headers ONLY for module A, then perhaps have a collection of the common headers in a .value/factory provider, which returns a $http with those headers modified.

Comment: Ok. So if I have to do the opposite, that is configure some common headers for my entire app, maybe the cleanest way to do it is to create a `configurator` module which performs the configurations which are shared by the entire app.

Comment: @leon Yes, that would solve the problem. Still, I think the way I thought it worked remains prettier, because I could have a module with its own modular functionality, with his own configurations for objects such as `$httpProvider`, which would make it highly more reusable in my opinion.

Comment: Yes it would seem that way, but I can't think of too many scenarios where you'd want a seperate $http object for every module. it's common for a single module to be responsible for all http requests, this seems like an edge case.

Answer (score 1):

In any one app, no matter what modules you pull in, all `services`, `factories` and `providers` are **singletons**.

You're using the `$httpProvider`, one such singleton... and therefore, by the very nature of singletons, any configuration done to a provider means **all modules are affected**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is how it works. See example.

```
angular.module("foo",[]).config(function($httpProvider){$httpProvider.test = 123});
angular.module("bar",["foo"])
  .config(function($httpProvider){console.log(httpProvider.test)}); //123
```